# Internet Explorer only works when going through a proxy

Tags: proxy, internet-explorer

This only affects Internet Explorer, others (Chrome, Opera, Vivaldi etc) works without problems.

Internet Explorer *only* works when running through a proxy.  That is, it works when Fiddler is open, and just to test, it also works when running through [tinyproxy](https://tinyproxy.github.io/). By "not work" I mean it just hangs on "looking up example.com...". It doesn't even timeout or anything.

I made a small code-snippet to check the default proxy in the system, since Internet Options reports no proxy active.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var target = new Uri("http://www.vg.no");

        var proxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
        var proxyUri = proxy.GetProxy(target);
        var bypassed = proxy.IsBypassed(target);
        Console.WriteLine($"Type of proxy object: {proxy.GetType().Name}\nNamespace of proxy object:{proxy.GetType().Namespace}\nTarget uri: {target.AbsoluteUri}\nProxy uri: {proxyUri.AbsoluteUri}\nIs target bypassed in proxy? {bypassed}");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

And the output is quite peculiar:

```
Type of proxy object: WebProxyWrapperOpaque
Namespace of proxy object:System.Net
Target uri: http://www.vg.no/
Proxy uri: http://www.vg.no/
Is target bypassed in proxy? True
```

If my code is right, it looks like it's trying to use itself as a proxy.. I can't for the life of me figure out what the problem is.

(Btw: When Fiddler is active, it reports `Proxy uri: http://127.0.0.1:8888` and `Is target bypassed in proxy? False` as expected.)

Anyone seen anything like this?

My proxy settings:

[image: Proxy settings]

My relevant registry settings: (ref [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/819961))

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]
"MigrateProxy"=dword:00000001
"ProxyEnable"=dword:00000000
"ProxyHttp1.1"=dword:00000001
"EnableHttp1_1"=dword:00000001
"ProxyOverride"="*.local"
"ProxyServer"="127.0.0.1:8123"
```

Comment: Do other browsers do the same thing?

Comment: No all other browsers work like normal, as I clumsily stated at the top. (*edit*)

Comment: Chrome uses the OS proxy settings.  When you tested chrome did you have a proxy configured?

Comment: No. This is an ongoing thing. The computer, including chrome, works perfectly. There is no proxy configured. Chrome works as expected. Internet Explorer only works when I use Fiddler (or another proxy).

Comment: This computer connected to an active domain?

Comment: No. But it has two NIC's. One is connected to the company intranet, and one is connected to the Internet. The computer is not a member of the intranet domain. (Local user). I tried inspecting the DHCP-packet from the intranet and did not find any reference to a proxy. (Using wireshark)

Comment: If you switch the cables around.  Does it work like you expect it to?  Do what is requires to test this configuration, then once you have, you can reverse it.  I won't have any other ideas until I have an answer to that question though (just how my brain works).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46448/discussion-between-christian-wattengard-and-ramhound).

Comment: Did you get this sorted out?

Comment: No... I've left that workplace now though ;)